# MATLAB symbolically solve equation for ratio of 2 variables

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

I have a pretty large equation in which I need to solve for a ratio of 2 variables/symbols. A small example would be:

Y = A*Y + B*X

and I want MATLAB to solve this as

Y/X = B/(1-A)

where the answer(Y/X) doesn't self-reference Y or X. Is there a way to make MATLAB do this for me?

I tried using the solve function to solve for y, then x, and then call "simple(y/x)", but the answer still referred to X and Y

Answer (score 1):

Express the equation in terms of a new variable `Z = Y/X` instead of `Y` (using `subs` to replace `Y` by `Z*X`), and then solve for `Z` (using `solve`):

```
>> solve(subs('Y = A*Y + B*X', 'Y', 'Z*X'),'Z')
ans =
    -B/(A - 1)
```